# Android Gallery Widget Error: java.lang.NullPointerException at android.widget.Gallery.setUpChild

Tags: android, android-view, android-gallery

The main Activity in my Android app has a Gallery widget that loads XML layouts (containing TextViews and Images) through an efficient ImageAdapter. For the most part this works fine and I haven't had any problems on any of my devices or the emulator, but I have seen the following error in my logs. It looks like this is affecting less than 1% of users, but I'd like to know what's causing it, how to resolve it, or at least "catch" it and resolve gracefully. Any ideas?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at
```

`android.widget.Gallery.setUpChild(Gallery.java:772) at` `android.widget.Gallery.makeAndAddView(Gallery.java:751) at` `android.widget.Gallery.fillToGalleryLeft(Gallery.java:667) at` `android.widget.Gallery.trackMotionScroll(Gallery.java:378) at` `android.widget.Gallery$FlingRunnable.run(Gallery.java:1369) at` `android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) at` `android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) at` `android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) at` `android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3695) at` `java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at` `java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) at` `com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842) at` `com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) at` `dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get this problem several days ago, please check your own gallery's adpater check its getView() methods,see if you return null in some if-cases,just replace return null with new View(context) (or other view but null) will simply solve this problem.Good luck

Comment: That's exactly what has happening. Thank you!